# Silverstripe 4 - Authenticator class not found

Tags: php, silverstripe, silverstripe-4

I would allow pre-generated users to log out from a SilverStripe 4 website front-end page, by using the default from. Logging out because log in works.

The problem is that if a logged generic user tries to log out by clicking on a link like `Security/logout` (as well as `Security/logout?BackURL=home/`), it being redirected to a blank page (just with header/footer visible, as the default `Page.ss` is implemented). Apparently the controller doesn't work or similar, because URL points me simply to `Security/logout` with no following redirects.

So, I tried to implement a custom authenticator, as I usually do in SS 3, but I noticed some little differences. Then, I followed both the [official doc](https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/4/developer_guides/security/authentication/) and the [suggested example](https://gist.github.com/sminnee/bc646147f3941a764d0410f2044433c7) for help.

This is the situation:

**MemberAuthenticator custom class**
(in *MySite/code*)

```
<?php
// Definizione Namespace
namespace Greylab\Corporate\Authenticator\UtenteAuthenticator;
use SilverStripe\Security\MemberAuthenticator\Authenticator;

/**
* Classe Autenticazione Utente
*/
class UtenteAuthenticator extends Authenticator
{
/**
 * Login Paziente - Getter
 * @param string $link URL di autenteicazione utente
 * @return object Form di autenticazione utente
 */
public function getLoginHandler($link)
{
    return UtenteLoginHandler::create($link, $this);
}
}
```

**MemberAuthenticator\LoginHandler custom class**
(in *MySite/code*)

```
<?php
// Definizione Namespace
use SilverStripe\Security\MemberAuthenticator\LoginHandler;
use SilverStripe\Control\Session;

/**
 * Clesse Login Utente
 */
class UtenteLoginHandler extends LoginHandler
{
    /**
     * Metodo gestione Login Utente
     * Setter
     * @param array $dati Dati form login
     * @param object $form Form login
     * @return void
     */
    public function doLogin($dati, $form)
    {
        $utente = $this->checkLogin($dati);

        // Controllo Utente
        if ($utente) {
            $cliente = Session::set('UtenteLoginHandler.MemberID', $utente->ID);
            $datiCliente = Session::set('UtenteLoginHandler.Data', $dati);

            $this->performLogin($cliente, $datiCliente);

            return $this->redirectAfterSuccessfulLogin();
        } else {
            // Se utente invalido torna al form
            return $this->redirectBack();
        }
    }
}
```

**MemberAuthenticator\LoginHandler custom class**
(in _MySite/*config/mysite.yml*)

```
SilverStripe\Core\Injector\Injector:
  SilverStripe\Security\Security:
    properties:
      Authenticators:
        UtenteAuthenticator: %$Greylab\Corporate\Authenticator\UtenteAuthenticator
```

With this implementation the system throw me this exception:

> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'SilverStripe\Security\MemberAuthenticator\Authenticator' not found in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/corporate/ss_corporate/corporate/code/UtenteAuthenticator.php on line 10

Anyone can suggest me the right way?

Thanks everyone in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need to use

```
use SilverStripe\Security\MemberAuthenticator\CMSMemberAuthenticator
```

Check out the docs:
http://api.silverstripe.org/4/SilverStripe/Security/MemberAuthenticator.html

Comment: Thanks @gavin, I changed the dependency and corrected the extension statement. Now the exception is solved, but I'm still stuck on blank page problem. I opened a new question about it. It can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50444572/silverstripe-4-blank-page-on-logging-out