# SilverStripe 4 - Blank page on logging out

Tags: php, silverstripe, silverstripe-4

As I stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50406958/silverstripe-4-authenticator-class-not-found), I would allow pre-generated users to log out from a SilverStripe 4 website front-end page, by using the default from. Logging out because log in works.

The problem is that if a logged generic user tries to log out by clicking on a link like `Security/logout` (as well as `Security/logout?BackURL=home/`), it being redirected to a blank page (just with header/footer visible, as the default `Page.ss` is implemented). Apparently the controller doesn't work or similar, because URL points me simply to `Security/logout` with no following redirects. Furthermore, the session is not being cleared and if I go back to the user dashboard page, it results still logged in.

So, I tried to implement a custom authenticator, as I usually do in SS 3, but I noticed some little differences. Then, I followed both the [official doc](https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/4/developer_guides/security/authentication/) and the [suggested example](https://gist.github.com/sminnee/bc646147f3941a764d0410f2044433c7) for help.

This is the situation:

**MemberAuthenticator custom class**
(in *MySite/code*)

```
<?php
// Definizione Namespace
namespace Greylab\Corporate\Authenticator\UtenteAuthenticator;
use SilverStripe\Security\MemberAuthenticator\MemberAuthenticator;

/**
* Classe Autenticazione Utente
*/
class UtenteAuthenticator extends MemberAuthenticator
{
/**
 * Login Paziente - Getter
 * @param string $link URL di autenteicazione utente
 * @return object Form di autenticazione utente
 */
public function getLoginHandler($link)
{
    return UtenteLoginHandler::create($link, $this);
}

/**
 * Logout Paziente - Getter
 * @param string $link URL di deautenteicazione utente
 * @return object Form di deautenteicazione utente
 */
public function getLogoutHandler($link)
{
    return UtenteLogoutHandler::create($link, $this);
}
}
```

**MemberAuthenticator\LoginHandler custom class**
(in *MySite/code*)

```
<?php
// Definizione Namespace
use SilverStripe\Security\MemberAuthenticator\LoginHandler;

use SilverStripe\Core\Injector\Injector;

/**
 * Clesse Login Utente
 */
class UtenteLoginHandler extends LoginHandler
{
    /**
     * Metodo gestione Login Utente
     * Setter
     * @param array $dati Dati form login
     * @param object $form Form login
     * @return void
     */
    public function doLogin($dati, $form)
    {
        $utente = $this->checkLogin($dati);

        // Controllo Utente
        if ($utente) {
            $request = Injector::inst()->get(HTTPRequest::class);
        $session = $request->getSession();
        $cliente = $session->set('UtenteLoginHandler.MemberID', $utente->ID);
        $profiloPaziente = Member::get()->byID($session->get('UtenteLoginHandler.MemberID'));
        $datiPaziente = $session->set('UtenteLoginHandler.Data', $dati);

            // Controllo Utente
        if ($profiloCliente) {
            $this->performLogin($profiloCliente, $datiCliente);

            return $this->redirectAfterSuccessfulLogin();
        } else {
            // Se utente invalido torna al form
            return $this->redirectBack();
        }
        } else {
            // Se utente invalido torna al form
            return $this->redirectBack();
        }
    }
}
```

**MemberAuthenticator\LogoutHandler custom class**
(in *MySite/code*)

```
// Definizione Namespace
use SilverStripe\Security\MemberAuthenticator\LogoutHandler;
use SilverStripe\Core\Injector\Injector;
use SilverStripe\Security\Security;
use SilverStripe\Security\IdentityStore;
use SilverStripe\Security\Member;
use SilverStripe\Control\HTTPResponse;

/**
 * Clesse Login Utente
 */
class UtenteLogoutHandler extends LogoutHandler
{
    /**
     * Metodo gestione Logout Utente
     * Setter
     * @param array $dati Dati form login
     * @param object $form Form login
     * @return HTTPResponse
     */
    public function doLogOut($utente)
    {
        // Controllo Utente
        if ($utente) {
            $request = Injector::inst()->get(HTTPRequest::class);
        $session = $request->getSession();
        $paziente = $session->get('UtenteLoginHandler.MemberID');
        $datiPaziente = $session->get('UtenteLoginHandler.Data');

        // Controllo Sessione Utente
        if ($paziente && $datiPaziente) {
            $session->clear('UtenteLoginHandler.MemberID');
            $session->clear('UtenteLoginHandler.Data');

            Security::setCurrentUser(null);

            return $this->redirectAfterLogout();
            // Tried with this approach too without success...
            /* if ($utente instanceof Member) {
            Injector::inst()->get(IdentityStore::class)->logOut($this->getRequest());
                return $this->redirectAfterLogout();
            } */
        } else {
            // Se sessione utente invalida torna al form
            return $this->redirectBack();
        }
    }
}
```

**MemberAuthenticator Injection**
(in _MySite/*config/mysite.yml*)

```
SilverStripe\Core\Injector\Injector:
  SilverStripe\Security\Security:
    properties:
      Authenticators:
        UtenteAuthenticator: %$Greylab\Corporate\Authenticator\UtenteAuthenticator
```

With this implementation, nothing changed.

Anyone can suggest me the right way?

Thanks everyone in advance.

Comment: SS4 Session APi changed [link](https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/4/developer_guides/cookies_and_sessions/sessions/) and why are you using Sessions for authentication. You didn't register your UtenteLogoutHandler like you did to the UtenteLoginHandler. Your doLogIn have `$this->performLogin($profiloCliente, $datiCliente);` which actually login the Member whereas in your doLogOut method you are not login out the Member but just clearing the Sessions. If you are to use your UtenteLogoutHandler as it is, your Member $cliente will still be logged in even after invoking the doLogOut.

Comment: add `if ($member instanceof Member) {
            Injector::inst()->get(IdentityStore::class)->logOut($this->getRequest());
        }` in your doLogOut. Please have a look at LogoutHandler.php

Comment: Hi @patjnr thanks for the tip, but at this time still don't work. As you can see from my updated code above, I tried with Security::setCurrentUser(null); as the API reference suggests, with the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a deep research, solution came from a brave official Slack Community member: special thanks to @[kinglozzer](https://silverstripe-users.slack.com/team/U2WNGDZ8C) for it.

Simply, SS 4 provides a brand new `$LogoutURL` default parameter to obtain the right logout url. It includes the logged-in member `SecurityID` as parameter. The old SS 3 `Security/logout` isn't enough anymore to run the process. So, by using:

`{$LogoutURL}&BackURL=<url>`

User will be logged out and redirected correctly.

Thanks anyone for help.